# Can't install applications (not enough memory) but Storage shows there is free memory

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, insufficient-memory, storage, sony-xperia

I'm trying to install an application from Play Store and after downloading it (about 25 MB) I'm gettin an error "not enough memory". My phone is Sony Xeria Tipo (ST21i) 4.0.4.

But in phone Settings I see that there is enough free memory:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why it happens so?

Answer (score 0):

Android upto **version 4.0**, has different partitions for application storage and storing normal user files, for imparting security on the apps.

As you can see even though  your internal Storage is 2.15GB, the total available memory for apps is only 754MB, of which your there is only 134MB available,

even though your downloaded app is about 25MB, it is in compressed state and will be extracted on install. So, you should either 'uninstall some of your unused apps' or 'delete appdata of already installed apps'.

If your phone is [rooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS))! checkout some apps on playstore to move apps to external SD card.